Cannot create a BACPAC from a file that does not contain exported data
enter image description here

Cannot create a .BACPAC from a file that does not contain exported data (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)

It happens when I want to import a .bacpac file into my SQL Server; I download from internet
Can anyone answer my questions and explain it to me?
